# Laravel 8 factories

Tags: laravel

Can someone tell me how can I make a factory with relationships etc...

I have a post table with 2 foreign keys: user_id and category_id
I need to generate dummy data but I don't know how to do it.

I have tried to make categories first then to do something with posts and users but did not work.

PostFactory:

```
public function definition()
{
    $title = $this->faker->sentence;
    $slug = Str::slug($title);
    return [
        'title' => $title,
        'slug' => $slug,
        'image' => $this->faker->imageUrl(900, 300),
        'content' => $this->faker->text(300),
    ];
}
```

CategoryFactory:

```
public function definition()
{
    $category = $this->faker->words(2, true);
    $slug = Str::slug($category);
    return [
        'category' => $category,
        'slug' => $slug
    ];
}
```

And user factory is just default one :)

Comment: Try creating the user when you create the post like it's in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#factory-relationships . Then it's the same with the category

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ but I want to do for example: generate 50posts, 7 categories and 20 users. If I do like in docs I will have 50posts 50categories 50users... that is not that practical :)

Comment: Oh, ok. So, when you are creating the posts, the users and the categories already exist in the database? That is, you run a factory first to create 20 users, then the factory to create the 7 categories, and finally you want to run this PostFactory using the existing users and categories?

Comment: Right now my DB is empty. So, now I want to generate some dummy data but problem is that I have 2 foreign keys in my posts table- user_id and category_id. Also, there are relationships, hasMany (User>Post) and belongsTo(Post>User, Post>Category), as well as hasMany(Category>Post).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if you have enough records, and query the DB to find a random User and Category to use on each Post. But if there not enough records (20 Users and 7 Categories), create a new one.

PostFactory:

```
public function definition()
{
    $title = $this->faker->sentence;
    $slug = Str::slug($title);
    $user = User::count() >= 20 ? User::inRandomOrder()->first()->id: User::factory();
    $category = Category::count() >= 7 ? Category::inRandomOrder()->first()->id: Category::factory();

    return [
        'title' => $title,
        'slug' => $slug,
        'image' => $this->faker->imageUrl(900, 300),
        'content' => $this->faker->text(300),
        'user_id' => $user,
        'category_id' => $category,
    ];
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm :D Thank you so much I was trying last 4 days to figure this thing out ... haha