# How to seed 2 tables that are related to each other in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

So I have 2 tables one is the User table and the other is the related UserProfile table. I wanted to fill them with dummy data but I cant get it to work that when I run the seeder it will fill both tables. For now it will fill the User table with dummy data only.

**Solution found(any sugestions are welcome)**

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

use App\Models\UserProfile;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{

    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    protected $table = 'user';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**UserProfile.php**

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\User;

class UserProfile
{
    protected $table = 'user_profile';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

**UserFactory.php**

```
namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = User::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->firstName,
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail,
            'active' =>  mt_rand(0,1),
            'role' => mt_rand(0,5),
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', 
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    }
}
```

**UserProfileFactory.php**

```
namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\UserProfile;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class UserProfileFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = UserProfile::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => User::Factory(),
            'firstname' => $this->faker->firstName,
            'lastname' => $this->faker->lastName,
            'default_language' => 'en',            
        ];
    }
}
```

**DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\User;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {

        //solution
        User::factory(100)->hasProfile(1, function (array $attributes, User $user) {
            return ['firstname' => $user->name];
        })->create();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can append `->each(function ($user) {
    factory(UserProfile::class, 1)->create(['user_id'=>$user->id]);
});`
to `User::factory(100)->create()`

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, but I answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64624884/laravel-8-factories) a while ago. You would have to adapt it to your case, but it can serve as an idea.

Comment: seen it and its sadly not the same :-)

Answer (score 1):

Could you give this a try:

```
public function definition()
{
    $user = [
        'name' => $this->faker->firstName,
        'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'active' => mt_rand(0, 1),
        'role' => mt_rand(0, 5),
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi',
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
    UserProfile::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id
        //any other extra data you have in the user_profiles table
    ]);

    return $user;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `for` method, [Belongs To Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#belongs-to-relationships)

```
UserProfile::factory()
    ->for(User::factory()->state([
        'name' => 'name',  // optional
        ...
    ]), 'profile')->state([
        'firstname' => 'firstname',  // optional
        ...
    ])->create();
```

or

```
$users = User::factory()->count(100)->create();

foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
    UserProfile::factory()
        ->for($user, 'profile')
        ->create();
}
```

Comment: this will return the error  ```Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\BelongsToRelationship::attributesFor() must be an instance of
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, instance of App\Models\UserProfile given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-dashboard\ba
ckend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory.php on line 398
```

Comment: You need to create factory for UserProfile. `UserProfile::factory()` is not a model, check the document.

Comment: found it I think, userProfile needed to be extend with the Model class

Comment: Its throwing a new error now ```SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `user_profile` (`first
name`, `lastname`, `default_language`, `id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Catharine, Wiegand, en, 4, 2021-07-07 15:44
:55, 2021-07-07 15:44:55))
```

Comment: Can you update your question? add what you have done

Comment: `has` is used for Has Many Relationships, try `for` like my code.

Comment: I understand but when using your example it will create 3 user records and just 1 user_profile which does not match will the user records

Comment: This will result into an error ```Call to undefined method App\Models\UserProfile::profile()
``` so replaced the profile for user and it will generate dummy data, sadly its not matching data